# I copied a unit test almost exactly the same but in mine when I asset_call_once_with I get an extra `bind` argument?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

The first of the unit tests below passes, but the second one fails.

```
# unit test passes
def test_fetch_display_name(self, rows, expected_display_name, index):
    """SQL is executed and the display name is returned."""
    index.object_id = 100
    mock_fetchall = mock.MagicMock(return_value=rows)
    mock_result = mock.MagicMock(fetchall=mock_fetchall)
    mock_session = index._db_session
    mock_session.execute = mock.MagicMock(return_value=mock_result)
    mock_bind = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_session.get_bind = mock.MagicMock(return_value=mock_bind)
    expected_param_dict = {
        "id": 100,
        "fid": 998,
    }

    assert index._fetch_display_name() == expected_display_name
    mock_session.execute.assert_called_once_with(
        SQL.GET_STATIC_VAL, expected_param_dict, bind=mock_bind
    )

# unit test fails
def test_has_constituents(self, index):
    mock_fetchall = mock.MagicMock(return_value=[['True']])
    mock_result = mock.MagicMock(fetchall=mock_fetchall)
    mock_session = index._db_session
    mock_session.execute = mock.MagicMock(return_value=mock_result)
    mock_bind = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_session.get_bind = mock.MagicMock(return_value=mock_bind)
    expected_param_dict = {
        "fid": 4633,
        "clid": 136,
        "ident": "cboe-buk100p-O"
    }

    assert index._has_constituents()
    mock_session.execute.assert_called_once_with(
        SQL.FETCH_INDEX_HAS_CONSTITUENTS, expected_param_dict, bind=mock_bind
    )
```

They are almost identical, but when I run the second one, I get:

```
    E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: execute('select val from sval where fid = :fid and id = (select id from id where clid = :clid and ident = :ident);', {'fid': 4633, 'clid': 136, 'ident': 'cboe-buk100p-O'}, bind=<MagicMock id='140712726575856'>)
E           Actual: execute('select val from sval where fid = :fid and id = (select id from id where clid = :clid and ident = :ident);', {'fid': 4633, 'clid': 136, 'ident': 'cboe-buk100p-O'})
E           
E           pytest introspection follows:
E           
E           Kwargs:
E           assert {} == {'bind': <Mag...12726575856'>}
E             Right contains 1 more item:
E             {'bind': <MagicMock id='140712726575856'>}
E             Use -v to get more diff

../../anaconda3/envs/jobserveee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_mock/plugin.py:455: AssertionError
```

In the second unit test, for some reason it picks up `bind` as an argument. But in the first it doesn't.

Any ideas if it is to do with the way I set it up, or if I missed something?

Comment: In the first test you call the method index._fetch_display_name() while in the second test you call the method index._has_constituents(). I suppose that both called methods cause the execution of the method `execute()`, but in the _fetch_display_name() is not passed the argument bind...